# Total derivative as generalized vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, jet-bundles

I've seen that it is possible to think the total derivative as a generalised vector field between $d_\alpha:J^1B\rightarrow TB$
Where $J^1B$ is the first order jet bundle.
But how an element of $J^1B$ is sent to one of $TB$?

My teacher said it's possible to define the mapping using the infinite jet bundle, but I don't see how it is possible.

Comment: Total derivative of what?

Comment: In this case I'm thinking about total derivative of a Lagrangian, i.e. the operator that act as $d_\alpha L=\frac{\partial L}{\partial x^\alpha}+y^i_\alpha \frac{\partial L}{\partial y^i}+y^i_{\alpha\beta}\frac{\partial L}{\partial y^i_\beta}+...$